# In Ruby, is scan() the only function that can return multiple results of regular expression matching?

Tags: ruby

Just to know more methods that can accomplish the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

`split( regex )` returns an array, leaving out all matches. Sometimes it's easier to specify what you don't want to see.

Answer (score 0):

There are only two methods in the standard library which match a regular expression multiple times: `gsub` (and `gsub!`, of course) and `scan`. `gsub` returns a single string, so, yes, `scan` is the only one the returns multiple results.

Comment: I kinda wish we had the `g` modifier for regex, like Perl does, as it seems to make sense having "global" apply to matches too. Or, maybe that's because I have to write in Perl a lot too.